# can't remove horizontal scollbar

Tags: html, css, horizontal-scrolling

I need the border of the title of this page to extend to the right side.

Perhaps there is a better way of doing this but I have used position:absolute and width:100% because the content div underneath needs to overlap.

This causes a horizontal scrollbar to appear. How can I get rid of that?

[problem site](http://areca.demoriata.com/about)

Comment: For a quick fix, apply `overflow-x: hidden;` to your `body` selector.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that. If no other solutions work, then I'll use that.

Answer (score 0):

Because of your absolute, adding a 100% to the element will extend it the size of the viewport from where it starts.

I believe what you're wanting to do can be accomplished by keeping the absolute there, but also adding a relative positioning to your `#content` rule:

```
#content {
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it won't fix it since I need the border to extend all the way to the edge of the page.